# Error : An exception occured during a webclient request(FTP) - Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I tried using this sample i got from a post here like :
I'm using powershell 2.0

```
$File = "D:\28.csv"
$ftp = "ftp://username:Pwd@IPAddress/in/28.csv"

"ftp url: $ftp"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$File)
```

I'm trying to upload a file to an FTP server
But i keep getting the error:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At D:\Scripts\test.ps1:14 char:22
+ $webclient.UploadFile <<<< ($uri,$File)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: I trap the error and its sayong "The requested FTP command is bot supported when using hTTp proxy".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

it will accept a string as the first parameter as well as System.Uri:

UploadFile                Method     byte[] UploadFile(string address, string fileName)

you could try this:

```
$webclient.UploadFile($ftp,$File)
```

Saw your comment after posting - you should edit you're question to include that info.

Have a look at this:

http://mycodetrip.com/2008/10/29/fix-for-error-the-requested-ftp-command-is-not-supported-when-using-http-proxy_118/

The gist:

> After a bit of investigation, I found that the error was happening
>   because the method call from SQL Server was attempting to use the
>   HttpProxy on the Server machine. If the proxy is not set to null
>   explicitly in your code, then you will get this error.

Comment: Solid answer. You may want to include the gist of the codetrip solution explicitly in case the link poofs.

Comment: Thanks guys but not setting the proxy at all in my code.The lin is using a different approach

Comment: This answer lead to solving my problem... I had recently turned on a Proxy setting in Internet Explorer, and (after reading this question and its reference to a Proxy), I see that this is what broke my PowerShell scripts which uploaded via ftp. Once I removed the Proxy settings from IE, my scripts began running fine again. Who knew that when you set a Proxy in IE it would affect other internet activities on the computer. I do now...

Comment: Same with finding a proxy configured on the system causing a similar error for FTP upload. No need to remove the proxy in IE (or winhttp) - just set the `System.Net.WebClient` proxy to $null after you instantiate it in the script. e.g. `$webclient.Proxy = $null`